# My modals are overlapping with each other and when the two is click then it triggers the same content

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry had to post again, because I didn't recieve a relevant answer to my last post, but I have got 2 modals added to my footer, like when you click on a button then a modal pops up with more info. The buttons that are modals are Subscribe and mouth off, but when you click on subscribe then it shows the mouthoff modal instead of the subscribe modal.

I have tried renaming the modals and searched the internet, including here and youtube, but nothing seems to be working. The tutrial i followed to make the modals was https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_bottom and i wish all my modals to be this design.

Edit: I have got the modals to show there separate content, but now when the subscribe button is clicked, then it opens, but the modal will not close when clicked off the modal or clicking on the X. My updated code is below

My HTML code is:

```
 <footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="social">
      <ul>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-twitch"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div class=" footer-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><button id="subscribe-button">Subscribe</button><div id="subscribe-modal" class="modal"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><span class="close">&times;</span></div><div class="modal-body"><h3>SUBSCRIBE TO THE Thunder Struck Games MAILING LIST</h3>
                    <p>Welcome to the Rockstar Games Subscription Management page. Rockstar mailing lists are the best way to get the early word on all our game announcements, official launches, contests, special events, and more. Make sure you're enlisted to receive all the updates.</p><a href="#" class="manage-button">Manage Your Account</a></div><div class="modal-footer"></div></div></div></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Support</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Careers</a></li>
          <li><button id="mouthoff-button">Mouthoff</button><div id="mouthoff-modal" class="modal"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><span class="close">&times;</span></div><div class="modal-body"><h3>MOUTHOFF - TELL US WHAT'S ON YOUR MIND</h3>
                    <p>Welcome to the Rockstar Games Subscription Management page. Rockstar mailing lists are the best way to get the early word on all our game announcements, official launches, contests, special events, and more. Make sure you're enlisted to receive all the updates.</p><a href="#" class="manage-button">Manage Your Account</a></div><div class="modal-footer"></div></div></div></li>
```

My CSS code is:

```
.footer-nav li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 11.25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.footer-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
}
button {
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
.modal-body h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.modal-body p {
  text-align: justify;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-right: 250px;
}
.manage-button {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px 22px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 850px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.modal-body a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
}
.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0} 
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

My Javascript code is:

```
// Get the Subscribe modal
var subscribeModal = document.getElementById('subscribe-modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var subscribeBtn = document.getElementById("subscribe-button");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var subscribeSpan = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
subscribeBtn.onclick = function() {
  subscribeModal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  subscribeModal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == subscribeModal) {
    subscribeModal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
// Get the Mouthoff modal
var mouthoffModal = document.getElementById('mouthoff-modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var mouthoffBtn = document.getElementById("mouthoff-button");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
mouthoffBtn.onclick = function() {
  mouthoffModal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  mouthoffModal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == mouthoffModal) {
    mouthoffModal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated and thank you in advance and again apologies for posting again

Comment: Still looking for assistance on this. If possible

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a different variable name for mouth-button and mouth-modal.

Comment: done that and now the subscribe modal will open, but is unable to close, when you click off the modal or even the x. Give me 15 minutes and I'll update the above

Comment: Can you share the link where you deploy your changes. Thanks

Comment: You changed the variable name "span" to "subscribeSpan" but didn't replace it where you are doing:
`span.onclick = function() {
  subscribeModal.style.display = "none"
}`
Try replacing `span` with `subscribeSpan` & test.

Comment: I change it but still unable to close the modal :/

Comment: Maybe not related to this issue but right now the code is fetching span element of subscribe modal(x button) two times by doing `getElementsByClassName('close')[0]`. For fetching x button of mouth modal shouldn't it be `getElementsByClassName('close')[1]`

Comment: Nope changing ClassName does nothing as both modals don't open now :/

Comment: Okay revert the change. Atleast the modal was opening before. Don't change any class name just try placing 1 instead of 0 for mouthspan and check what happens.

Comment: Now mouthoffSpan doesn't close :/

Comment: Does subscribe modal closes though?

Comment: Yeah the Subscribe modal closes